# C# send a string and Java received wrong string via Socket

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I have a problem when sending and receiving a string via socket. My application includes a c# client and java server. C# will send a string:

c# code:

```
 this.WriteByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(variable))
 this.WriteByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value.ToString()));
 reader.ReadBoolean();


 private void WriteByteArray(byte[] buffer)
    {
        writer.Write(buffer.Length);
        if (buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer);
        }
    }
```

and Java receive :

```
int lenght=readIntFromDotNet(reader);
        if(lenght>0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[lenght];
            reader.read(buffer, 0, lenght);
            return new String(buffer);
        }
```

Problem: the received string is wrong .

example: C# send **"Variable"** and java receive **"V a r i a b l e"**

What's wrong in my code?

**Solved**: i have used "UTF-16LE"

```
return new String(buffer,"UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: It may work but there is no guarantee that the `reader.read(....)` call will fill the buffer. The third parameter passed to this method is the maximum length to be read, not the absolute length.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would do the trick for you

```
this.WriteByteArray(variable)
reader.ReadBoolean();
void WriteByteArray(String message)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    AsyncCallback ac = new AsyncCallback(SendStreamMsg);
    tcpClient.GetStream().BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ac, null);
}
```

on the Java side

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockServer.getInputStream(),utf8));
String message = br.readLine();
```